# how to get LLVM IR with debuginfo from linux kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling

I get the following linker error when trying to build linux kernel, help me please to fix the issue.
[click to see the screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OEgCSJ9Y1HlG57ltlmizr9ACujpJ3HJD/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance.